# Recursive functions in C and printf

Tags: c, recursion, printf

So, first of all I'm a total beginner in C, we're studying it at University on the course 'Structured Programming'.

Now, the last few lectures about 'Recursive functions' have been a pain for me as a beginner. Could anyone of you be kind enough to explain me this:

So I have this little script, a recursive function that takes a decimal number and converts it to a binary one:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void binary(int num)
{
    if (num == 0) return;

    binary(num / 2);
    printf("%d", num % 2);
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    binary(n);
    return 0;
}
```

Now I was wondering, how does this function work? I know the logic behind it and whats its supposed to do, but I don't know how it does IT. The printf in the bottom is especially throwing me off, for example if the printf function is before the recursive call, for the input decimal 10 it prints out (0101) but if its under it it prints out the correct binary number (1010)?

Any kind of help is greatly appreciated, kind regards.

Comment: "Execute" your program naively "by hand" with a pencil and a piece of paper and you'll understand.

Comment: Note that the function doesn't print anything when `n` is zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reversal is done using the call stack of the functions. By that I mean that the way the functions are called, this guarantess that the `MSB` will be printed first then the next one and so on.

```
void binary(int num)
{
    if (num == 0) return;

    binary(num / 2);  // Wait, I will print but you first print the MSB's.
    printf("%d", num % 2); // Now I print the last digit.
}
```

---

Downward motion moves the calls.

```
{binary(12)                     
   {binary(6)                 
      {binary(3)        
        {binary(1)  
             binary(0) -- returns
        Now we print 1
        }
      print 1
      }
   prints 0
   }
prints 0
}
```

Comment: I was unaware of this, but thanks to you and @Michael Waltz, its a lot more clear now. I'll spend some time on the book reading more about the call stack, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If one wants to print recursively the bits of a char with leading zeros,
he may use following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_bit_iter(char x, int n)
{
    int bit = (x & (1 << n - 1)) != 0;
    printf("%d", bit);

    if(n != 0)
      print_bit_iter(x, n - 1);
}

int main()
{
  print_bit_iter('U', 8);
}
```

This will have

```
01010101
```

as the output.

Comment: what's that `#include <iostream>` ;)